# How to print category tree in JSON with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, tree, categories

I'm having some issues doing the function to print a category tree in JSON.

These are my tables:

**tb_category**

```
ID_CATEG                    CATEGORY
   1                       Category 1
   2                       Category 2
   3                       Category 3
```

**tb_subcategory**

```
ID_SUBCATEG                   SUBCATEGORY              ID_CATEG
    1                         Subcategory 1               1
    2                         Subcategory 2               2
    3                         Subcategory 3               2
    4                         Subcategory 4               2
    5                         Subcategory 5               3
    6                         Subcategory 6               3
```

How can i print a JSON, with **PHP**, like this:

```
{
    [
        "category": "Category 1",
        "subcategories": {
            "Subcategory 1"
        }
    ],
    [
        "category": "Category 2",
        "subcategories": {
            "Subcategory 2",
            "Subcategory 3",
            "Subcategory 4"
        }
    ],
    [
        "category": "Category 3",
        "subcategories": {
            "Subcategory 5",
            "Subcategory 6"
        }
    ],

}
```

Or something like that.

Comment: In PHP, or MySQL? What have you tried? What do "categories" really have to do with it?

Comment: that is not a valid JSON. you can't have associated arrays inside "[]" and you can't have arrays in "{}"
here is the sql command you'll probably need. fix your JSON and result can be converted to that.
`$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_subcategory JOIN tb_category ON tb_subcategory.ID_CATEG = tb_category.ID_CATEG";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //convert result to correctly formatted JSON 
}`